# How to Display a browser content in a LED TV Monitor

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a cricket scoring web-based project where I need to display the scorecard page in a separate Large LED TV Monitor where the scorer has a different page to score in the browser, how I'm gonna achieve this? Any suggestions?

Technologies I'm using : Java, JSP, Servlets, HTML, CSS, JQuery, Javascript

Comment: Are you asking how you would output to the TV or how you would write the application?

Comment: @mikea Yes, I have a web page where scores are updating continuously, and what I want to do is output that page into the TV

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a PC with a graphics card with two outputs, so you can attach two monitors.

The next step depends on your OS. Configure it to display one big desktop on both screens. now, you just need to open a new browser window with coordinates that are on the second big LED TV.

Answer (score 0):

A number of large screen LED TVs have build in web browsing capabilities. You could possibly make use of one of those to output the result.

Alternatively you would need a separate device to drive the TV. In which case I would suggest an android tablet. Very easy to set up and a number of them (nexus) come with hdmi output.